# why is this content security policy violation telling me to add a hash that already exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

When I moved my assets from the Rails asset pipeline to webpacker, I started getting CSP violations that said to add the same hash twice:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256-LHNh9xw1VeZTANwMt4DeW/YM2X358wyOgpJN8RDGF1U='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-LHNh9xw1VeZTANwMt4DeW/YM2X358wyOgpJN8RDGF1U='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

Why is that? I read that webpacker serves files from port `3035` by default, and that this could interfere with the content security policy, so I changed the port in my CSP's `connect_src` directive to `:self, :https, 'https://example.ngrok.io:3000', 'wss://example.ngrok.io:3000'` and my **webpacker.yml** config to this:

```
development:
 dev_server:
  https: false
  host: localhost
  port: 3000
  public: localhost:3000
```

`3000` being the port my app runs on.

So I guess this is two questions: 1) why is my CSP telling me to add the same hash twice, and 2) does webpacker need to serve files from the same port that my app runs on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to run the webpacker dev server on the same port as your rails server as it will just fail to start as the port will already be in use. It works on the old assets pipeline as your rails server was actually serving the assets. Not 100% sure but maybe add `localhost:3035` to the CSP?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is likely that hashes work on inline style tags, not style attributes. Even though the style attribute hash won't work, the browser still suggests it in the error message. The best option is to move the styling into a css file. Your current implementation might work if you add 'unsafe-hashes' of CSP level 3, but this is currently only implemented in Chromium browsers.

Comment: what is the difference between a style attribute and a style tag? i thought they were the same thing, but i may be misreading you. in any case, i'm using a framework called Fomantic UI. My markup is `<div class="ui dropdown">x<div class="menu"></div></div>` and then i have `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();` in my webpacker **application.js** file's `turbolinks:load` listener. When I click the x, a couple classes and `style="display: block !important;"` are added to `<div class="menu">`. How would I move *that* into a css file? This worked no problem in the old asset pipeline.

Comment: Style tags would be like <style>.classname{display: block !important;}</style> while the style attribute could be <div ... style="display: block !important;">. How to move it into a css file or mitigate it in other ways depends on the framework/library. Some of them are just not CSP friendly at all.

Comment: Got it, thank you! And yeah I've noticed this is a thing. It's weird how unfriendly these frameworks are!